# Is TLS supported in Distributed Tensorflow gRPC communication

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-tensorflow

I was wondering is TLS supported in current distributed tensorflow with gRPC?

I am reading through the code, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.h#L105

the implementation of GetServerCredentials
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc#L417

Looks like TLS is not supported (https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/)

So my questions is: 
1) double check TLS is not supported in case i missed something.
2) if currently not support, what's the plan?